# Как в WolframAlpha задать несколько символов в качестве единой переменной в математическом выражении

Tags: математика, переменные

Мне необходимо подавать математические запросы на WolframAlpha через .Net реализацию, но такую конструкцию, как ma, которая означает медиану треугольника на сторону а, он воспринимает, как m*a. Как объединить символы в одну переменную?

Comment: m_a можно использовать?

Comment: Не, я пробовал. Ничего не выходит. Может какая то функция есть, которая строку к одной переменной сводит